# Open modern image file dialog in SPFx web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

By using the "Quick links" client-side web part on a modern site page it is possible to add a new link and set an optional image by a file dialog.

[image: file dialog]

Is it possible to use this kind of file dialog in any other custom web part or was it built just for the "Quick links" web part?

Comment: have you tried UI fabric for this ??
https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/dialog

Comment: Fabric gives you an empty Dialog box, you still have to provide the Dialog content yourself

Comment: Yes I'm already using the Office Fabric dialog but defined the content on myself. Currently I'm building a Web Part that also needs such a file dialog to choose an image. So before redeveloping the wheel I'm wondering if there are any "finished" generic file dialogs available for such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think its from custom fields library for SPFx
[from here](https://oliviercc.github.io/sp-client-custom-fields)

Comment: https://oliviercc.github.io/sp-client-custom-fields

Comment: You can add some details from the link.